# Alternative for array comparison for performance improvement

Tags: java, android, performance, cpu-usage

I have a `thread` which compares two long `arraylist` after every one sec (Obviously one arraylist changes and so I compared). The performance is reduced and the CPU utilisation is increased drastically. I want to know of a solution to increase my CPU performance. What can be a good way? Is there any other Way than using array list.

Comment: It depends what you are comparing and what algo you are using to compare?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to achieve by the comparison, and what data you have in the two lists ?

Comment: I am using bubble sort algorith and both the arraylist contain objects of same datatype.

Comment: why are you using bubble sort? The built-in sort functions will be a load faster.

Comment: Can u give details about "built-in sort functions"?

Comment: [List.contains(object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @jelies : I am comparing to get the new object..I dont get the "object" u r checking to see if it is into the list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Collections framework contains methods for sorting ArrayLists (and other collections for that matter) that will perform more efficently than your implementation of a bubble sort, which is O(n^2), worst case - you will be able to achieve an O(n log n) using collections.

The usage will be:

Collections.sort(yourArrayList);

There is an example of the usage here:
http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/03/12/java_comp.html

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your ArrayList and just store whether or not it's changed. So, if you change it, do something like `boolean changed = true`. Then when you want to check, instead of iterating through the entire list, you can just check `if(changed)`. Then remember to set `changed = false` each time you've checked it.

Comment: But what if one just want to have changed data ? in that case one need to have the comparison ?

Comment: the problem is i am not changing the list and the list is retrieved from the system.I just compare the old list with the new 1 to check for an event

Comment: @AbhishekB: oh ok. That wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AbhishekB: Why dont you use observer pattern means if anything is changed it will automatically update theobserver with the value.